# What is the optimal icon size for XPages Mobile Control line items in views?

Tags: ios, webkit, xpages, mobile-controls

I have been adding icons to my mobile control Line Item controls and haven't quite figured out what the preferred size of these icons should be. The CSS has max size settings of 35 by 35px.

The reason I ask this is because the icons don't seem to line up correctly. The CSS positions them at 0 0. If all else fails I may modify CSS and position them to something other than 0 0.

Still interested in hearing how you have dealt with this.

Comment: I think it's 10mm*10mm - the size of your finger tip - will confirm

Comment: Paul you haven't seen my fingers lately have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the teamroom template, the mobile view for Recent Activity has icons that line up with the text. All these images are 16 X 16px.

There will never be 1 fit for all, the layout will be dependant on font size, row height and where you want it to line up. Some people may want it to align in the middle vertically and others will want it to align with the title in the row.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 21px x 21px. but that depends on what font-size you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Icon size can depends upon the applicaton. Normal size is 32x32 and an extended icon size is 64x64. If you want to line up the icons, you might have to change the icons to a standard size.